# A particular PHP script is not read on my LAMP server temporarily, while other work fine

Tags: php, apache

I have a very weird problem. I am using a standard LAMP server running on Ubuntu. The server is hosting lots of different PHP scripts. Every now and then, a particular PHP script is not being read (i.e, when I type its address into the browser nothing happens). After about 10 minutes the script is read and everything looks normal.

The ***odd*** thing is, that when I first ran into this problem I changed the script to be simply:

```
die('The file is read');
```

And even then the script is not processed - it seems Apache (or something else) is refusing to load it. When this happens, I can get to all other scripts with no problem at all (so it is not a downtime on my server or something). As I mentioned before, after awhile (*about 10 minutes*) I can get to the script just fine (*until the next time it happens*).

Could it be that Apache blocks a particular script for some reason (*maybe some kind of frequency cap?*). Could there be another reason why a simple script (with just a `die` call in it) could fail to respond, while all other scripts work fine?

I have been dealing with this situation for some time now, and asked many others and still haven't found an answer or a solution.

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: do you have some additional apache module load? some strange recursive rewrite rule or else?  Are you accessing it with "localhost" or some other name that your dns may try to search somewhere?

Comment: Have you tried changing the file name?

Comment: What about your Apache logs? Is there any entries about requesting those files? What does Firebug (or similar) tells you about request? Is it executes?

Comment: Check if you have AppArmor or SELinux active

Comment: Make sure you have `display_errors` set to `on` plus `log_errors` and `error_log` configured. Many people using packages such as LAMP do not have their servers configured as development servers.

Answer (score 0):

If Apache is doing something funny, it will usually log into the error_log at least. You may have to increase the general logging (with [LogLevel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#loglevel))  to show it though.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I will check it out once I will catch this wired behavior again.